# How to set focus on jsTree custom DOM (Select tag) in node?

Tags: jquery, html, jstree

Please look this JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PersianMan/v66hwc0v/

```
var x= "<select id='drp'><option value='1'>One</option><option value='2'>Tow</option><option value='3'>Three</option></select>";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#using_json_2').jstree({ 'core' : {
        'data' : [
            { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Choose: " + x },
            { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2", "state" : { "opened" : true } },
            { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 1" },
            { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" }
        ]
    }}).on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
      $("#drp").focus();
    });
});
```

I want to add a custom DOM (in this case Select element), in the [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/demo/) node that user can change its value.

After use my code, element was added to the node, but after click on select element, **select list open and close very fast!** and user can't choose option.

Do you have any idea?